# file creation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Small question:

Is it possible to make new file using JavaScript? I'm looking for something like the PHP function `fopen` and `fput`. Is this totally impossible? And what about JavaScript function `OpenTextFile()`?

Comment: @IswantoSan That is not a dupe, both the Q and A imply IE and ActiveX.

Comment: Can you give more information about the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @jwrush , actually i need to put some data in a new txt file. so i need to create first and then put data.

Comment: That can't be one from the client side. Send the data to the server, then serve a new txt file for download.

Comment: Is the text file just for storing data you're going to use in the javascript application later, or do you need to use it otherwise like a text file, i.e., in other applications?

Comment: in the txt file storing data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only possible with HTML5 apparently.

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=exNerx1ZaKk

And here's creating text files:

[create a text file using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403912/create-a-text-file-using-javascript)

Comment: i have used the second link in IE . but no result. Is it need any special plug in ?

Comment: i used it in my site ( linux server ) .

Comment: You need ActiveX plugin installed.

Comment: will you please make me clear . 
This plugin is for IE . ok . But is it work in linux server ? 
I mean i wanna use this file in my site hosted on linux server. possible ?

Comment: I did not write the solution in the link, merely found the link for you. I don't see why it wouldn't work on a linux server. The only thing I can think is that it may not work on the latest versions of IE as ActiveX was dropped. Give me 5 mins and I'll look a bit further into it.

Comment: Instead of using the ActiveX approach which is a little defunct there is HTML5 file api. The best code I could find is here which creates the file but with no file extension. Can't be that far off: http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/html-xhtml-xml/62439-how-create-text-file-html5-using-file-api.html

Comment: actually it is really need an extension. but your link give me a door.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources to get you started.

**Writing to a file/directory:**
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

**Downloading a file:** http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/a.download.html

**Downloading a zip:** http://stuk.github.com/jszip/

**Reading a file**: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

***The top 2 only work in chrome.***

*jszip* has mixed support, and reading files with HTML5 has support in all modern browsers.

It is possible to set the data to a link's href. But a user will have to right click > save link as and add the extension.

```
<a id="test" target="_blank">click me</a>

document.getElementById('test').href = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + escape("Your String goes here");
```

Comment: it just download a file with `part` extension. 
but i need to create a `.txt` file. possible ?

Answer (score 0):

In the browser, no. Server-side (as in node.js), yes.

There is no js function to open a text file from the file system, but you can fetch the contents of a text file on your server with an Ajax request.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/

Comment: I suspect the File API won't do what slash-bang is looking for, as I suspect he wants to do general file IO in pure js, so bfavaretto is right in spirit.

Comment: Right, I forgot about the file api. That solves reading local files on modern browsers, but not writing.

Comment: +1 good point. But it's possible to open a text file using `XMLHttpRequest` on local filesystem.

Comment: @metal_fan Is it? I don't think so.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sure. http://phpjs.org/functions/file_get_contents/

Comment: @metal_fan That just takes a URL and uses Ajax to fetch the file. It's for remote files, not local files.

Comment: @bfavaretto yep XHR is a point here. No, it works for both local and remote files. (another example: Jquery UI Autocomplete that can fetch and parse XML from **local files**) using ajax

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27362/discussion-between-bfavaretto-and-metal-fan)