# How can i create a text file using java script in Unicode encoding?

Tags: javascript

[Unicode Encoding...  Gettting UTF-8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoMks.png)
I am using this code...

```
    var content = 'demo';
    uriContent = "data:application/text," + encodeURIComponent(content);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', uriContent);
    link.setAttribute('download', '22ddd' + '.txt');
    link.click();
```

The content in the text file will be in Hindi Language which will be further converted into APS fonts. The font converter software available with the client works when the encoding is Unicode. I am able to download the text file properly but it is in UTF-8 encoding

Comment: Have you looked at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403912/create-a-text-file-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create a text file using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403912/create-a-text-file-using-javascript)

Comment: @oneNiceFriend: I don't think the questioner wants to use `ActiveX` to create a textfile. It's old and works only with Internet Explorer.

Comment: Please can you add to your question what isn't currently working? What's wrong with the encoding? `UTF-8` looks like an unicode encoding for me..

Comment: The content in the text file will be in Hindi Language which will be further converted into APS fonts. The font converter software available with the client works when the encoding is Unicode. I am able to download the text file properly but it is in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: UTF-8 *is* Unicode.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoMks.png

Comment: While saving the text file in Notepad, option of encoding displays both UTF-8 as well as Unicode. After saving it in Unicode encoding, the client's software is able to read it and convert it in APS Fonts (Converted) from Mangal (Original).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) says,`encodeURIComponent` generates only `UTF-8`. So we must try something different.

I tried to put some pieces together:

- a modern browser (Chrome 56) and
- a [text-econding polyfill](https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding)

and it works (for me):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>window.TextEncoder = window.TextDecoder = null;</script>
        <script src="encoding-indexes.js"></script>
        <script src="encoding.js"></script> 
        <script>           
            demo = function() {
                var content = 'demo';
                var uint8array = new TextEncoder( 'utf-16', { NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding: true }).encode(content);
                var blob = new Blob([uint8array], {type : "octet/stream" });
                var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.setAttribute('href', url);
                link.setAttribute('download', '22ddd' + '.txt');
                link.click();       
            };
        </script>
        <button onClick="demo();">
            Test
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please note that I don't understand why I have to put `uint8array` in an array to create the blob. Any explanation?